# Get column size using Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to retrieve metadata information of a table; I am successful of retrieving the columns and type of the columns in a table. I want to retrieve each columns size as well. I am fairly new to Hibernate and am stuck with this.  This is how I retrieved column names and types:

```
String[] columns = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()
            .getClassMetadata(Java.class).getPropertyNames();
Type[] columnsType = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()
            .getClassMetadata(Java.class).getPropertyTypes();
```

Entity class:

```
@Entity
    @Table(name="Box")
    public class Box implements Serializable {
        private int dimHeight;
        private int dimLen;
        private int dimWidth;
        private double weight;

        public Box() {
        }

        public int getDimHeight() {
            return this.dimHeight;
        }

        public void setDimHeight(int dimHeight) {
            this.dimHeight = dimHeight;
        }

        public int getDimLen() {
            return this.dimLen;
        }

        public void setDimLen(int dimLen) {
            this.dimLen = dimLen;
        }

        public int getDimWidth() {
            return this.dimWidth;
        }

        public void setDimWidth(int dimWidth) {
            this.dimWidth = dimWidth;
        }

        public double getWeight() {
            return this.weight;
        }

        public void setWeight(double weight) {
            this.weight = weight;
        }
    }
```

Code and exception is :

```
Field foo = Box.class.getField("dimWidth");
foo.setAccessible(true);

java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: dimWidth
    at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1520)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HibernateUtil` doesn't expose that. However, you can simply use Java reflections for that:

```
Field foo = Java.class.getField("foo");
Column column = foo.getAnnotation(Column.class);
column.length();
```

**Update**

Grrrhh, made a stupid mistake... `getField()` is only for public members. You need to use `getDeclaredField()` for private fields like so:

```
Field dimWidthField = Box.class.getDeclaredField("dimWidth");
Column columnAnnotation = dimWidthField.getAnnotation(Column.class);
System.out.println(columnAnnotation.length()); // 5
System.out.println(columnAnnotation.precision()); // 0

private class Box implements Serializable {
  @Column(length = 5, precision = 0)
  private int dimWidth;
```

Comment: What if the class which I am referring to has all "private" variables.  Doesnt "java.lang.reflect.Field" will be able to access "Public" variables ? Correct me if I am wrong Please.

Comment: @Satya, if you get exceptions accessing a field you can force access like so `foo.setAccessbile(true)` before calling `getAnnotation()`. However, I'm pretty sure you can get annotations of private fields even without forced access.

Comment: I was getting "NoSuchMethodException" so I forced the access. I am still getting the same exception

Comment: @Satya, you need to post your entity class, the exception stacktrace and the code you use to get the annotations (update your original post for that).

Comment: Sorry was busy with some other stuff.  Anyways changed the original post

Comment: I tried to get the details of Field only, but its failing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Am I using the right api? 

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import javax.persistence.Column;

field.getAnnotation(Column.class) is 'null', but I am getting fields back when I do field.getDeclaredFields()

Comment: @Satya, that's nothing but logical because the code you posted doesn't contain `@Column` annotations.

Comment: My bad, cant believe how stupid I was.. I had the annotations for other fields in the file and didnt have for the above mentioned variables. Anyways corrected my mistake its working fine now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the wrong place. As its name indicates, ClassMetadata contains metadata about a class, and not about a database table and its columns.

To get information about the columns of a table, use [JDBC's DatabaseMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Using the above code I have written, I was successfully able to retrieve information about the columns like type and column name in the table except the size. I am not sure if I can use DatabaseMetaData with hibernate configuration ?